# How to dynamically set an inputcheckbox as selected, based on id

Tags: apex, apexinputcheckbox

I have a table that shows list of contacts. List is dynamic

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Duplicate Records" rendered="{!hasDuplicateResult}">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!duplicateRecords}" var="item">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageSection">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox label="{!item['Id']}" value="{!selectedContactId}" selected="{!IF({!selectedContactId},true,false)}" >
                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!selectContactToMerge}" event="onclick" >
                            <apex:param id="bee" name="bee" value="{!item.id}" assignTo="{!bee}"/>
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!item['Id']}">{!item['Name']}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!item['OwnerId']}"/>
            </apex:column>                
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Account</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!item['AccountId']}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Last Modified Date</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!item['LastModifiedDate']}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

When a checkbox is selected, I update a field in my controller:

```
public void selectContactToMerge() {
    selectedContactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bee');
    system.debug('selectedContactId : ' + selectedContactId);
}
```

When the page rerenders, I want that the selected inputcheckbox will be selected.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: As far as my eyes can see, you are setting the variable `selectedContactId` in the method `selectContactToMerge()` which is executed when you check the checkbox... so if you don't check it, you will never have the variable Id set, therefore, the checkbox will never be checked. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does, but that' what I am trying to do. The list renders on every click, and the checkbox does not return as checked.